# Drawbitmaps on tablets

Tags: android, android-animation

I built an application with sprite animation of bitmaps, it runs fine on small devices (with 480X320 bitmaps) but if i want it to run on tablets i need very large bitmaps (1200X800) and this makes the app work very slow and also makes a memory problem.

any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Most tablets will run Honeycomb or later so you should activate hardware acceleration in your manifest:

```
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

To combat the memory problem you can try several things

1. use 16bit Bitmaps.
2. recycle unused bitmaps
3. use smaller and less bitmaps
4. switch to Renderscript or OpenGL

Comment: the application is designed for android 2.1, i cant set hardwareaccelerated.

Comment: sure you can. simply up the sdk level. If you dont use new apis you app will work on 2.1 but will make use of hardware acceleration on tablets.

Comment: i changed the hardware acceleration but it didnt changed the canvas acceleration, just the surfaceview